Stations in the subnets browse the internet but cannot see each other (ip route 2 ISPs)
On my router (ubuntu/NFTables) I configured two WANs, one from each different ISP.
In the current configuration, I can ensure that any machine in the subnets can navigate using the first or second link, according to the rule in NFTables.
Note that it is not a specific LAN interface (any machine on any LAN interface can browse any of the two links with public IPs according to the rule in NFTables)
This is working, ok.
The problem I'm facing now is that the machines on the subnets should see each other and they're not even pinging each other.
Does anyone know how I can fix it so that, in addition to maintaining internet browsing like this, I can make machines connected to LAN1, LAN2, LAN3 and LAN4 able to talk to each other?
Below is the netplan configuration:
network:
ethernets:
    wan1:
        addresses:
        - 111.31.111.2/28
        - 111.31.111.3/28
        - 111.31.111.4/28
        - 111.31.111.5/28
        - 111.31.111.6/28
        - 111.31.111.7/28
        - 111.31.111.8/28
        - 111.31.111.9/28
        - 111.31.111.10/28
        - 111.31.111.11/28
        - 111.31.111.12/28
        - 111.31.111.13/28
        - 111.31.111.14/28
        nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 8.8.8.8
            - 8.8.4.4
            search: []
        routes:
        - to: default
          via: 111.31.111.1
          metric: 100
        - to: default
          via: 111.31.111.1
          metric: 100
          table: 100
        routing-policy:
        - from: 192.168.10.0/24
          table: 100
        - from: 192.168.20.0/24
          table: 100
        - from: 192.168.30.0/24
          table: 100
        - from: 192.168.40.0/24
          table: 100
    wan2:
        addresses:
        - 222.63.222.10/29
        - 222.63.222.11/29
        - 222.63.222.12/29
        - 222.63.222.13/29
        - 222.63.222.14/29
        nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 8.8.8.8
            - 8.8.4.4
            search: []
        routes:
        - to: default
          via: 222.63.222.9
          metric: 200
        - to: default
          via: 222.63.222.9
          metric: 200
          table: 200
        routing-policy:
        - from: 192.168.10.0/24
          table: 200
        - from: 192.168.20.0/24
          table: 200
        - from: 192.168.30.0/24
          table: 200
        - from: 192.168.40.0/24
          table: 200
    lan1:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.10.1/24
    lan2:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.20.1/24
    lan3:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.30.1/24
    lan4:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.40.1/24
version: 2

Following tables and rules:
userrouter1@router1:~$ ip route
default via 111.31.111.1 dev wan1 proto static metric 100 
default via 222.63.222.9 dev wan2 proto static metric 200 
192.168.10.0/24 dev lan1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.1 
192.168.40.0/24 dev lan4 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.40.1 
111.31.111.0/28 dev wan1 proto kernel scope link src 111.31.111.2 
222.63.222.8/29 dev wan2 proto kernel scope link src 222.63.222.10

userrouter1@router1:~$ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
32756:  from 192.168.30.0/24 lookup 200 proto static
32757:  from 192.168.40.0/24 lookup 200 proto static
32758:  from 192.168.20.0/24 lookup 200 proto static
32759:  from 192.168.10.0/24 lookup 200 proto static
32760:  from 192.168.30.0/24 lookup 100 proto static
32761:  from 192.168.10.0/24 lookup 100 proto static
32762:  from 192.168.40.0/24 lookup 100 proto static
32763:  from 192.168.20.0/24 lookup 100 proto static
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

userrouter1@router1:~$ ip route show table 100
default via 111.31.111.1 dev wan1 proto static metric 100 

userrouter1@router1:~$ ip route show table 200
default via 222.63.222.9 dev wan2 proto static metric 200 

userrouter1@router1:~$ ip rule show table 100
32760:  from 192.168.30.0/24 lookup 100 proto static
32761:  from 192.168.10.0/24 lookup 100 proto static
32762:  from 192.168.40.0/24 lookup 100 proto static
32763:  from 192.168.20.0/24 lookup 100 proto static

userrouter1@router1:~$ ip rule show table 200
32756:  from 192.168.30.0/24 lookup 200 proto static
32757:  from 192.168.40.0/24 lookup 200 proto static
32758:  from 192.168.20.0/24 lookup 200 proto static
32759:  from 192.168.10.0/24 lookup 200 proto static


As it currently stands, if I'm on machine 192.168.10.10 I can't PING 192.168.20.10, nor vice versa... I needed to resolve this issue, maintaining navigation to external IPs like this.
Can anyone help me?

Your custom policy rules lead to tables which don't have any of the "local subnet" routes that the main table has. There's only the default route that matches everything, and so everything goes to your ISP.
You need either to add throw ("fall-through to next policy rule") routes into each of those tables,
ip -4 route add throw 192.168.0.0/16 table 100

or use an additional policy rule that does a second lookup in 'main' before custom tables instead of after (with a special option to ignore the default route).
ip -4 rule add pref 20 lookup main suppress_prefixlen 0


It seems like "add throw" is more elegant. However, is it due to some error on my part when configuring the routes?

Local subnet routes don't automatically show up in alternate tables – there's nothing more to it. The kernel only puts them in 'main' table and if you have any higher-priority rules then naturally those routes will not be reached.
